# How to check if Object is NOT in array in mongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to push Object in members array, if it's not there.
is there way to check if Object is not in array in mongodb?

```
{
 _id: 1111,
 members:[
 {user_id: 11},
 {user_id: 12},
 {user_id: 13}
 ]
}
```

So I want to check if:

```
newUser = {user_id: 14}
```

is not in members array, if not - push it there.
Stuck with it. Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: You can try `db.collection.update(
   { _id: 1111 },
   { $addToSet: { members: {user_id: 14}  } }
)`. This will not do anything if the value is already present. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#value-already-exists

Comment: thanks will try it

Comment: @Veeram that will match document with `_id: 1111` each time your run this query. And it will try to update document each time

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I assumed OP's wants to update the doc in question. So query for `_id` and update using `$addToSet`.

Comment: @Veeram might be, but in question OP states *'is there way to check if Object is not in array in mongodb?'* And example below also about checking whether `newUser` is in members array.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I agree. You are answering to the OP's needs.

Comment: thank you guys. answer accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $nin operator to check whether `members` array not contains document with `user_id` equal to 14. Update is simple $push:

```
db.collection.update({'members.user_id':{$nin: [14]}}, {$push:{members:{user_id:14}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check if the array in the document contains that specific object. Use [`elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for this

```
db.collection.find(
   { _id: 1111, members: { $elemMatch: { user_id: 14 } } }
)
```

Then, if the above returns nothing you pushing the object into

```
db.collection.update(
   { _id: 1111 },
   { $push: { user_id: 14 } }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = await Trans.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
              _id: data.id,
              'products.id': { $nin: [product.id] },
            },
            {
              $inc: {
                actualCost: product.mrp,
              },
              $push: {
                products: { id: product.id },
              },
            },
            { new: true }
          );
```